# Laptop doesn't detect USB Bootable

Tags: boot, windows-11, bootable-media

I'm trying to fix my laptop because the EFI partition went missing suddenly.

And I bought a USB Drive to boot to installation mode, but when I inserted the USB it doesn't work. I tried inserting it into another usb port but it also doesn't work.

I re-burned the Win11 ISO again using Rufus, I tried doing:

- MBR
- Changed to GPT and set the File System to FAT32
- Set the File System to NTFS(Still GPT)

and it still doesn't work.

Laptop Brand: Persona

USB Stick: Toshiba TransMemory? 32GB

Also, I can't boot to BIOS

Comment: What model is your computer? Have you looked for some boot option inside the BIOS?

Comment: @harrymc I can't boot into BIOS

Comment: The problem might not be the EFI partition. What errors do you get when trying to boot to BIOS or with the boot USB?

Comment: @harrymc I don't get any errors, my laptop power button just lights up for a few seconds then shutsdown. With the USB, same as the above. I feel like my laptop doesn't detect the USB.

Comment: I think you have a much more serious problem. You should have a repair-shop look at the computer.

Comment: `using Rufus` .. Rufus is a really cool program but you ideally want to use the windows media tool to do this.  I have had problems using Rufus with windows media which went away when I used the media tool.